# Automation -File Upload-Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have to weekly upload text files from a server location  to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  .I wish to automate the task so that files are automatically uploaded .Can somebody suggest me the way?

Comment: If you have tried anything then feel free to post here!

Comment: SSIS? `sqlcmd`and Task Scheduler? This is far too broad as it stands and seems like you're asking for tool recommendation (which is off topic for Stack Overflow). Try to solve the problem yourself, describe/show your attempts, and the problem your having with your solution; such as error messages, undesired/unexpected behaviour, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Methods I know of:-

Via SQL:

- Use OPENROWSET to open the file and obtain the records to write into
  a table.
- Use BULK INSERT to open the file and insert directly into a table (you may need to pair with XP_CMDSHELL to get a directory listing to loop through)

VIa SSMS:
Create a DataFlow to import from file

SSMS makes it easier to do clever things with the import process. But it can be very finnicky.

With both of those you can set up an Agent job to run the script / package automatically.